# Removing printed lines in Python 3

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to build a game.
The game will have an item called a "pulsating crystal" (I am using `\033[1;31;40m]` to change the items colour), I want to it to be rainbow, so it keeps changing colours, without deleting everything else in the terminal. I used print(`\033c`) to clear the terminal but I just want to print the last line. I am sorry if the question is unclear or repetitive, or has another answer but I couldn't find another clear answer for my problem. PS I use Linux.

Comment: please share the relevant code you have so far

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to print the last line.

To print a line repeatedly, just override the line ending `\n` by giving the keyword argument `end='\r'` to `print()`.